# Problema con procedure y workbench

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Tengo un procedimiento que llena una tabla con datos para su posterior consulta, para ello usa dos vistas, si ejecuto desde un gestor de base de datos como HeidySql el procedure me funciona correctamente, pero si cargo el procedure en el workbench e impacto la base de datos desde alli directamente, me genera el siguiente error desde una aplicación java:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Invalid default value for 'base_cuotclie_vencimiento_base'
```

No se si puede ser por el driver jdbc derrepente!

Anexos

Vista Base (1)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW clientes_movimientos_base_cco_v AS 
SELECT 
c.cuotcliecco_empr_codigo       base_empr_codigo, 
c.cuotcliecco_sucu_codigo       base_sucu_codigo, 
c.cuotcliecco_movi_codigo       base_movi_codigo, 
v.vent_cli_codigo            base_cli_codigo, 
v.vent_mon_codigo            base_mon_codigo, 
c.cuotcliecco_cuotclie_secuencia         base_cuotclie_secuencia_base, 
c.cuotcliecco_cuota_numero  base_cuotclie_cuota_numero_base, 
c.cuotcliecco_vencimiento           base_cuotclie_vencimiento_base, 
c.cuotcliecco_opertipo_codigo   base_opertipo_codigo_base, 
c.cuotcliecco_operacion_numero  base_operacion_numero_base, 
v.vent_fecha_documento       base_fecha_base, 
v.vent_comprobante           base_comprobante_base, 
c.cuotcliecco_monto          base_monto_base, 
v.vent_cotizacion            base_cotizacion_base, 
v.vent_situacion             base_situacion, 
c.cuotcliecco_cco            base_cco 
FROM cuotas_clientes_cco c 
INNER JOIN ventas v 
ON v.vent_numero = c.cuotcliecco_operacion_numero;
```

Vista complemento (2)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW clientes_movimientos_complemento_cco_v AS  
SELECT 
c.cobr_empr_codigo           complemento_empr_codigo, 
c.cobr_sucu_codigo           complemento_sucu_codigo, 
c.cobr_pers_codigo           complemento_pers_codigo, 
c.cobr_mon_codigo                complemento_mon_codigo, 
0                            complemento_cuotclie_secuencia_complemento, 
0                                complemento_cuotclie_cuota_numero, 
c.cobr_opertipo_codigo       complemento_opertipo_codigo_complemento, 
c.cobr_numero                complemento_operacion_numero_complemento,  
c.cobr_fecha_documento       complemento_fecha_complemento, 
c.cobr_comprobante           complemento_comprobante_complemento, 
d.cobrdetacco_monto              complemento_monto_complemento, 
c.cobr_cotizacion            complemento_cotizacion_complemento, 
d.cobrdetacco_cuot_secuencia complemento_cuotcli_secuencia_origen, 
c.cobr_situacion             complemento_situacion, 
d.cobrdetacco_cco            complemento_cco 
FROM cobros c 
INNER JOIN cobros_detalles_cco d 
ON d.cobrdetacco_operacion_numero_cancelacion = c.cobr_numero
```

Procedure Principal

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_cargar_clientes_movimientos_cco; 

DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_cargar_clientes_movimientos_cco( 
empresa INT, 
sucursal INT, 
centroCosto INT, 
persona INT, 
moneda INT, 
usuario INT 
) 
BEGIN 
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS clientes_movimientos_base_cco;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE clientes_movimientos_base_cco 
(INDEX temp_base_cuotcie_sq_i (base_cuotclie_secuencia_base))
SELECT * FROM clientes_movimientos_base_cco_v b 
where b.base_empr_codigo = empresa
and (b.base_sucu_codigo = sucursal or sucursal = 0)
and (b.base_cco = centroCosto or centroCosto = 0) 
and (b.base_cli_codigo = persona or persona = 0) 
and b.base_mon_codigo = moneda;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS clientes_movimientos_complemento_cco;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE clientes_movimientos_complemento_cco 
(INDEX temp_cuotclie_origen_sq_i (complemento_cuotcli_secuencia_origen))
SELECT * FROM clientes_movimientos_complemento_cco_v c
where c.complemento_empr_codigo = empresa
and (c.complemento_sucu_codigo = sucursal or sucursal = 0)
and (c.complemento_cco = centroCosto or centroCosto = 0) 
and (c.complemento_pers_codigo = persona or persona = 0) 
and c.complemento_mon_codigo = moneda;

DELETE FROM clientes_movimientos_cco where cliemovi_usu_codigo = usuario;
INSERT INTO clientes_movimientos_cco 
SELECT 
usuario                                                 cliemovi_usu_codigo,
b.base_empr_codigo                                      cliemovi_empr_codigo,
b.base_sucu_codigo                                      cliemovi_sucu_codigo,
b.base_movi_codigo                                      cliemovi_movi_codigo, 
b.base_cli_codigo                                       cliemovi_cli_codigo,
b.base_mon_codigo                                       cliemovi_mon_codigo,
b.base_cuotclie_secuencia_base                          cliemovi_cuotclie_secuencia_base,
b.base_cuotclie_cuota_numero_base                       cliemovi_cuotclie_cuota_numero_base,
b.base_cuotclie_vencimiento_base                        cliemovi_cuotclie_vencimiento_base,
b.base_opertipo_codigo_base                             cliemovi_opertipo_codigo_base,
b.base_operacion_numero_base                            cliemovi_operacion_numero_base,
b.base_fecha_base                                       cliemovi_fecha_base,
b.base_comprobante_base                                 cliemovi_comprobante_base,
b.base_monto_base                                       cliemovi_monto_base,
b.base_cotizacion_base                                  cliemovi_cotizacion_base,
b.base_situacion                                        cliemovi_base_situacion,
b.base_cco                                              cliemovi_centcost_codigo_base,
c.complemento_cuotclie_secuencia_complemento            cliemovi_cuotclie_secuencia_complemento,
c.complemento_cuotclie_cuota_numero                     cliemovi_cuotclie_cuota_numero_complemento,
c.complemento_opertipo_codigo_complemento               cliemovi_opertipo_codigo_complemento,
c.complemento_operacion_numero_complemento              cliemovi_operacion_numero_complemento,
c.complemento_fecha_complemento                         cliemovi_fecha_complemento,
c.complemento_comprobante_complemento                   cliemovi_comprobante_complemento,
c.complemento_monto_complemento                         cliemovi_monto_complemento,
c.complemento_cotizacion_complemento                    cliemovi_cotizacion_complemento,
ifnull(c.complemento_situacion, b.base_situacion)       cliemovi_situacion,
c.complemento_cco                                       cliemovi_centcost_codigo_complemento
FROM clientes_movimientos_base_cco b
left JOIN clientes_movimientos_complemento_cco c
ON c.complemento_cuotcli_secuencia_origen = b.base_cuotclie_secuencia_base
and c.complemento_situacion = 'VIGENTE';

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Cristian el error se corta,  pero parece indicar un error en un valor por defecto, quizás podrías añadirlo completo.

Comment: Asi mismo es Carmen, al crear las tablas temporales que estan dentro del procedure (un campo tipo date) se da error posiblemente, hoy despues de probar mucho descubrí que en el workbench al inicio de los sql el colocaba este código: sql_mode='TRADITIONAL' antes de crear el procedure... cosa que otro gestor como el Heidysql no necesita hacer... con eso básicamente solucione hasta ahora el problema, pero gracias por el comentario!

Comment: Por ahí iba mi idea, me alegra que lo hayas solucionado, deberías añadir la solución para dejar respondida la pregunta.

Comment: Dale, lo haré!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al crear las tablas temporales que estan dentro del procedure (donde hay un campo tipo date) se da el error posiblemente, hoy despues de probar mucho descubrí que en el workbench al inicio de los sql el colocaba este código: sql_mode='TRADITIONAL...' antes de crear el procedure... cosa que otro gestor como el Heidysql no necesita hacer... con eso básicamente solucione hasta ahora el problema!